# Rounding double value to value ending on .0 or .5

Tags: c#

I'm trying to round some values as the following examples and need some help to write the math calculation for it:

```
input -> 25 ÷ 4 = 6.25        output -> 6.5

input -> 15.5 ÷ 4 = 3.875     output -> 4.0

input -> 24.5 ÷ 4 = 6.125     output -> 6.0
```

any idea how to write the round math procedure please?!

Comment: Edited a bit because asp.net is not relevant to the question

Comment: I tried the Math.round() function... but the result is not what I'm looking for...

Comment: And edited to update title/remove tag from title.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: thanks for mentioning and help :|

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Thanks for mentioning and help :|

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.

```
double Divide(double numerator, double denominator)
{
    double result = numerator / denominator;

    //round to nearest half-integer
    result = Math.Round(result * 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) / 2;

    // due to peculiarities of IEEE754 floating point arithmetic
    // we need to round again after dividing back by two
    // to avoid a result like 1.49999999.
    return Math.Round(result, 1);
}
```

Comment: 25/4 giving 6.25 as resualt and I put it in ur code. the result I got is 6

Comment: Read the paragraph after the code to see the explanation why.

Comment: Hey, it's fixed for at least your samples. You probably want to come up with a good set of unit tests, though. I'm worried it only works because I'm using constants, and the compiler fixes it to use safe division. Variables the compiler can't optimize might have different results.

Comment: Yes, Exactly... I came up with another work around based on ur first code, and got the result. ur new solution is giving the exact result as well. thank you! I'll leave my work around as well... which may useful for those who are not using c#

Comment: But funny I should say I need to wait another 6 hours to answer my question... anyway... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not aware the difficulty you encountered, so I guess maybe the different types of floating point number. Following code just does that:

```
public static decimal RoundedDivide<T>(T a, T b) {
    var x=2*Convert.ToDecimal(a)/Convert.ToDecimal(b);
    x=((int)(.5m+x)>x?1:0)+(int)x;
    return x/2;
}
```

Two things to note:

1. I cannot bound a constraint of `ValueType`, so if you pass objects of reference types, it may throw
2. If you wish `double` as the return type, then just change it and also change `.5m` to `.5`, `Convert.ToDecimal` to `Convert.ToDouble`